# Trying to call a method using reflection and automatically parsing input

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to allow a user to call any method on a server using sockets and reflection. The client already knows the method names and the number of parameters, but not the actual parameter types.

Every method on the server takes 0 or more primitive arguments (including strings) and returns a primitive. I'm taking input from the user in the client using a Scanner, so everything is a string, and I'm using .split(" ") to separate the parameters.

How do I automatically parse these strings into their correct types (int, double, boolean, char, etc) on the server?

Here's what I'm currently doing on the server.
clientOutput and clientInput are an ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream on the socket, and m is the method I'm calling.

```
Class<?>[] parameterTypes = m.getParameterTypes();
clientOutput.writeObject(parameterTypes.length);
clientOutput.flush();
Object[] parameters = (Object[]) clientInput.readObject();
for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.length; i++) {
    //Some sort of if statement? Some way to handle booleans or chars?
    parameters[i] = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse((String) parameters[i]);
}
result = m.invoke(math, parameters);
```

And then I send the result (which is an object) back to the client, and it prints it out.

Comment: why can't the client know the parameter types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate through the parameter types, check for the class name and parse it accordingly.

```
                    for ( Class<?> c : paramTypes )
                            if ( "int".equals(c.getSimpleName() ) {
                                  // parse int
                            }
                            else if ("boolean".equals(c.getSimpleName() ) {
                                  // parse boolean
                            }
                     }
```

Comment: So, something like this?
`if("int".equals(parameterTypes[i].getSimpleName()))

parameters[i] = Integer.parseInt(parameters[i].toString());`

Answer (score 0):

If the method indicated in the incoming string resolves to one method by reflection, the server can surely get the parameter types for the method call, and parse each incoming String to the correct type.  Overloaded methods might be a bit more cumbersome: Verifying whether or not the incoming string is parseable as the parameter type could be able to single out the correct method.  If not, then proper error handling or reporting should occur.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea, but how do I know what type to parse each incoming string to?

Comment: As Kal's answer suggests: the paramTypes.